# modify certain values using ifelse condition in pipe

Tags: r

Suppose I have data frame as below:

```
df <- structure(list( 
 name = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"),
 val = c(100, 200, 300, 400, 0.15, 0.22, 0.31, 0.48)),
 .typeOf = c("factor", "numeric"),
 row.names = c(NA, -8L),
 class = "data.frame")
```

I want to visualize data using line plot over the bar plot. However, as you might see the data have different scales, co I cant visualize them normally. I need to introduce second Y-axis and rescale values of object "B" from the data frame respectively. For this purpose I use follow code:

```
df %>%
{
 assign("scaleFactor", ifelse(max(.[.$name == "A",2], na.rm = T) > max(.[.$name == "B",2], na.rm = T),
                              max(.[.$name == "A",2], na.rm = T) / max(.[.$name == "B",2], na.rm = T),
                              max(.[.$name == "B",2], na.rm = T) / max(.[.$name == "A",2], na.rm = T)), 
         envir = baseenv())
 . } %>%
 mutate(val = ifelse(max(.[.$name == "A 1",2], na.rm = T) > max(.[.$name == "B",4], na.rm = T),
                     .[.$name == "B",2] <- .[.$name == "B",2] * scaleFactor,
                     .[.$name == "A",2] <- .[.$name == "B",2] * scaleFactor))
```

First of all I need to calculate scale factor. It works fine. Then I need to multiple values of object "B" by scaleFactor. Here I have a problem. It returns second column with only one value which repeated. Seems that in this case *ifelse* condition do not work as vectorized function.

However, if I use *ifelse* condition out of pipe/mutate it works.

```
ifelse(max(df[df$name == "A",2], na.rm = T) > max(df[df$name == "B",2], na.rm = T),
       df[df$name == "B",2] <- df[df$name == "B",2] * scaleFactor,
       df[df$name == "A",2] <- df[df$name == "A",2] * scaleFactor)
```

Any ideas how can I modify/multiply certain values using *ifelse* condition in pipe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bas provided you with a solution, but you don't necessarily have to scale it beforehand!

`ggplot2` allows you to introduce a secondary axis that is linearly scaled from the first. A pretty good example may be found [here](https://whatalnk.github.io/r-tips/ggplot2-secondary-y-axis.nb.html)

The star of the show is this piece of code

```r
scale_y_continuous(
    name = expression("Temperature ("~degree~"C)"), 
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . * 400 / 30 , name = "Precipitation (mm)"), 
    limits = c(0, 30))
```

Here you can see the manually added scale, e.g. 400/30. In your case, this would be 833, as per Bas. Here is the result from the example I linked:

[image]

Word of caution that you no doubt already considered, [plots with two Y-axises are often misleading](https://blog.datawrapper.de/dualaxis/), and should be used with great care.

Just to recommend an alternative, `facet_wrap` allows you to facet by a factor or variable ([Docs](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Facets_(ggplot2)/)), or you could use `ggarrange` from `ggpubr` to make two individual plots which are then shown side by side.

Comment: Great answer, and TIL. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the answer and provided links

Answer (score 2):

Assigning values to columns within a `mutate()` statement (as you do with e.g. `.[.$name == "B",2] <-` ) is not the way you're supposed to use `mutate`, and is going to give headaches.

The below code gives the output you expect. I replaced the `ifelse` with a `max(max_val) / max_val`, which immediately gives the `scaleFactor` you want.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(max_val = max(val, na.rm = T)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(scaleFactor = max(max_val) / max_val,
         val_scaled = val * scaleFactor)
```

Which gives

```
# A tibble: 8 x 5
  name     val max_val scaleFactor val_scaled
  <chr>  <dbl>   <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>
1 A     100     400             1        100 
2 A     200     400             1        200 
3 A     300     400             1        300 
4 A     400     400             1        400 
5 B       0.15    0.48        833.       125 
6 B       0.22    0.48        833.       183.
7 B       0.31    0.48        833.       258.
8 B       0.48    0.48        833.       400
```

I kept the extra columns in there so that you can see what happened. You can drop them by `select()`ing only the columns you want.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You solved my problem, however my question is still unanswered. Since using mutate I can not change/modify certain values which function/method should I use? may be case_when (also does not work)?

Comment: Using mutate, you can change certain values using for example `ifelse`, but the new values should be the **result of** the `ifelse` statement, and should not be done **inside** the `ifelse` statement. That's simply not the way `mutate` works. You could do such things outside of the mutate but not within. If you want to approach it as a pipe, you have to use a method similar to what I proposed.